# How can I recreate the drop down button to be able to reveal the links from the side but the button stays in the same position?

Tags: html, css

[image][image]

[i am new to website design, any help is appreciated]
This code is for having the dropdown button links appear in a list form, what i am trying to do is when you hover over the "More about Us", the links will show on the right side of the button

```
[HTML]
<div class ="Links">
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">More About Us</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Employees</a>
    <a href="#">What we do</a>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
  </div>

</body>
</html>


[CSS]
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: outset;
  font-family: Agency FB;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #B9DADC;}
```

Comment: really, i dunno what are you tring to do. try to post more detail, a more exaustive image(how it's now and how you want it be ), some code

Comment: I have added more steps to what i needed

Answer (score 0):

OK, if now i understand what do you want you can solve this adding the position at the .dropdown-content.

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 100%;
  top:0;
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: outset;
  font-family: Agency FB;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  /*SET POSITION TO THE RIGHT AND TOP OF PARENT BOUNDARIES*/
  left: 100%;
  top:0;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #B9DADC;}
```

```html
<html>
      <body>
        <div class ="Links">
        <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">More About Us</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Employees</a>
        <a href="#">What we do</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
      </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I loose the fact that you want the link displayed all inline. To achieve this you have to set a fixed dimensione of .dropdown-content like :

```
width: 350px;
```

and the display of a element, like

```
display: inline-block;
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: outset;
  font-family: Agency FB;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  /*SET POSITION TO THE RIGHT AND TOP OF PARENT BOUNDARIES*/
  left: 100%;
  top:0;
width:350px;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
display:inline-block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #B9DADC;}
```

```html
<html>
      <body>
        <div class ="Links">
        <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">More About Us</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Employees</a>
        <a href="#">What we do</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
      </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is not sure the best solution but at the moment it is the only solution that comes to my mind.
Maybe you can try playing with

```
display: flex;
```

adding it to the .dropdown-content and then working on child element